# Send string as Query Filter in Linq to Objects

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile

I use sqllite in a Mobile Project (.net core 3.0) and Like I did in a web project with EF core (.Net 5), I wrote this:

```cs
InsAndOuts = await context._database.Table<Data.InOut>().ToListAsync();
var InsAndOutsQ = InsAndOuts.AsQueryable();

if (filter)
{ 
    InsAndOutsQ = InsAndOutsQ.Where(args.Filter); //<= This line is the problem

    InsAndOutsQ = InsAndOutsQ.Where(td => td.IsIn == isIn || td.IsIn == !isOut)
        .Where(td => td.Date >= model.StartDate && td.Date <= model.EndDate);
}

if (sort)
{
    InsAndOutsQ = InsAndOutsQ.OrderBy(args.OrderBy); //<= this line also get error
}
```

I don't need efficiency here sincce the list are not many, The errors are:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Func<MobileBlazorHybrid.Data.InOut, bool>'  MobileBlazorHybrid  C:\...\MobileBlazorHybrid\MobileBlazorHybrid\WebUI\Pages\InOut.razor    343 Active
```

and

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.   MobileBlazorHybrid  C:\...\MobileBlazorHybrid\MobileBlazorHybrid\WebUI\Pages\InOut.razor    351 Active
```

The filter and orderby is built dynamically by a datagrid, that works in a .Net 5 with Ef core 5 but here I have sqllite and no EF core and .net is 3.0.
How to fix this?

Comment: what are `args.Filter` and `args.OrderBy`?  What are their types and what values do they contain?

Comment: they are strings that are generated by a datagrid like this: "((Text == null ? \"\" : Text) == null ? \"\" : (Text == null ? \"\" : Text)).ToLower().Contains(\"sa\".ToLower())"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite and using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core
Solved my problem.